# C# Print Two Pages

Tags: c#, printing

Hello I want to print two different pages.

So I try this

```
int a = 50;
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    SolidBrush sbrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black);

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.picture1, 30, 20, 150, 50);
    e.Graphics.DrawString("OPERATION NAME", myFont_baslik, sbrush, 80, 100);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPen, 50, 130, 770, 130);
    e.Graphics.DrawString("1/2", myFont_yazi, sbrush, 750, 30);

    if (a >= 50)
    {
        e.HasMorePages = true;
        a = 40;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        e.HasMorePages = false;
    }


    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
    e.Graphics.DrawString("RESULT", myFont_altbaslik, sbrush, 50, 50);

    e.Graphics.DrawString("No. \t Radius \t Diameter", myFont_altbaslik, sbrush, 50, 80);
    e.Graphics.DrawString("No. \t Radius \t Diameter", myFont_altbaslik, sbrush, 450, 80);

    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i < 56)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[i].ToString(), myFont_yazi, sbrush, 50, 100 + i * 18);
        else
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[i].ToString(), myFont_yazi, sbrush, 450, 100 + (i - 56) * 18);
        }
    }

    e.Graphics.DrawString("2/2", myFont_yazi, sbrush, 750, 30);
}
```

I see two pages in printdialog. It is OK. But physically printer prints only last page. I want to print both pages. How can I solve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I may be missing something... But I can't see anything in your code which would cause anything to print? Do you mean physically print from an ink printer, or virtually print on to the screen?

Comment: @Ben After printdialog physically print  from an ink printer

Comment: The most obvious bug in this code is that the `a` variable does not get reset back to 50.  So it works in preview but if you then actually print next then `a` has the wrong value and HasMorePages won't be set to *true*.  Use the BeginPrint event to initialize `a`.

Comment: @Hans Passant thanks it works